# Not able to download small files but can download large files

Tags: servlets, grails, amazon-s3, groovy

I am using the code below to download files from S3. The code works well for medium to large file sizes, however, for extremely small file sizes (3kb - one line in TXT file) the download fails.

//controller

```
def download() {
   Request request = Request.get(params.int("id"))
   response.setContentType("application/octet-stream")
   myService.downloadFileFromS3(request.origFileName, response)
}


void downloadFileFromS3(String fileName, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String fullFileNameWithExtension = fileName
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=${fullFileNameWithExtension}")
    InputStream is = getS3Client().getObject(getBucketName(), fullFileNameWithExtension).getObjectContent()
    OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream()
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length
    log.info("This is the length: " + length)
    while ((length = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        log.info("Came here with length: " + length)
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length)
    }
    is.close()
}
```

Log out put for small files:

```
This is the length: 0
Came here with length: 15
GroovyPagesServlet:  "/WEB-INF/grails-app/views/request/download.gsp" not found
```

Log output for large files:

```
This is the length: 0
Came here with length: 1024
Came here with length: 1024
Came here with length: 1024
Came here with length: 1024
Came here with length: 1024
Came here with length: 1024
Came here with length: 1024
Came here with length: 1024
Came here with length: 1024
Came here with length: 1024
Came here with length: 1024
Came here with length: 531
```

So it seems that for small files it is looking for `download.gsp` view. But it should not be looking for that view since I am putting stuff in the `response`

Comment: How does it fail? What exceptions are being raised? What errors are you getting? You need to provide more details.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore I've updated with more details.

Comment: Try a `outputStream.flush()` before you return from the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Joshua Moore's comment is probably the correct answer.

However, I would recommend refactoring the code slightly to make it a little cleaner.

1) First of all try to avoid passing web-related objects (like request, response) to the service layer. You can refactor this by having your service layer method return an OutputStream. In the service method you just create a ByteArrayOutputStream that will hold the content of the file downloaded from S3. Then you'll write the contents of that output stream to `response.outputStream` within the controller. This will make it easier to test and keep your code DRY (i.e. you can now use this method to download a file from S3 without coupling that with writing the file contents to the response).

2) Also you should rename the `request` variable declared in the controller method since `request` is an implicit variable.

**MyService**

```
def amazonWebService
OutputStream downloadFileFromS3(String filename) {
    InputStream inputStream = amazonWebService.getS3("us-east-1").getObject(getBucketName(), filename).getObjectContent()
    OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length
    log.info("This is the length: " + length)
    while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        log.info("Came here with length: " + length)
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length)
    }
    if (inputStream) inputStream.close()
    return outputStream
}
```

**MyController**

```
    def myService
    def download() {

        // NOTE: I would recommend not using `request` as a variable 
        // name here since it's already an implicit variable 
        Request thatOtherRequest = Request.get(params.int("id")) 

        def filename = thatOtherRequest.origFileName
        def outputStream = myService.downloadFileFromS3UsingAwsSdk(filename)

        response.setContentType("application/octet-stream")
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=${filename}")
        response.outputStream << outputStream
        response.outputStream.flush()
        return
    }
```